# Lucene - find indexes where all search parameters are present?

Tags: asp.net, lucene.net

Lets say I have indexes as such:
1. Black Lilly Knitted Shirt
2. Black Knitted Shirt
3. Black Knitted Jeans

I want to run a search term "black knitted shirt" and return 1. and 2.

Meaning, only indexes containing search keywords are returned. How do I query Lucene to get such results?

Answer (score 0):

Either

- black AND knitted AND shirt
- "black knitted shirt"~1

The first means match where the field MUST contain each term.

The second is a slop phrase. The 1 means one "operation" can be performed in order to match. See [other slop answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36116558/277700) for some more info.